# Rule of mysql next-key lock?

Tags: mysql, sql

this is a mysql next-key lock problem. I hava a table 'gaptest', and its statement is

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `gaptest`;
CREATE TABLE `gaptest` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `var1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `var1` (`var1`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=101 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of gaptest
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `gaptest` VALUES ('1', '5');
INSERT INTO `gaptest` VALUES ('5', '10');
INSERT INTO `gaptest` VALUES ('30', '10');
INSERT INTO `gaptest` VALUES ('10', '20');
INSERT INTO `gaptest` VALUES ('15', '30');
INSERT INTO `gaptest` VALUES ('20', '40');
INSERT INTO `gaptest` VALUES ('40', '55');
INSERT INTO `gaptest` VALUES ('25', '60');
```

Here's what I did

1. In session1 I open transaction and execute "DELETE FROM gaptest WHERE var1 = 10;"
2. In session2 I open transaction, first execute "insert into gaptest select 9,20;", it blocked. When I execute "insert into gaptest select 29,20;" it's not blocked.

Why is the first statement blocked and the second is not?

Comment: Hello, I tried your example and had no blockings...maybe you have some pending operation?
Autocommit disabled?

Answer (score 0):

In session 1, there are next-key locks as below:

```
-- format by (var1, id)
((5, 1), (10, 5)]
((10, 5), (10, 30)]
((10,30), (20, 10)]
```

For (20, 9), it falls into the last range, so it will be blocked.
For (20, 29), it's out of the range, so it won't be blocked.

You need to consider range for `var1` as well as `id`. So, with `var1=20`, `id` less than 10 will blocked, and `id` larger than 10 won't.